# css pagination highlight the chosen page number

Tags: css, highlight

I am looking for a way to highlight the chosen page number in pagination using css,
or to make the chosen page number bold.

the pagination php code works fine so I think I should modify the css page.

what should I add here:

```
body
{
padding:50px;
font-size:0.85em;
font-family:arial;
}

a
{
text-decoration:none;
color:#0080ff;
}

a:hover
{
text-decoration:underline;
}



.info
{
line-height:150%;
width:650px;
overflow:auto;
margin-top:30px;
color:#555555;
}

.msg
{
padding:10px;
border-bottom:dashed 1px #5d478b;
width:450px;
margin-bottom:15px;
}

#pages
{
clear:both;
list-style-type:none;
overflow:hidden;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#pages li
{
float:left;
}

#pages li a
{
font-weight:bold;
margin:0 4px;
padding:5px 10px;
border:1px solid #bbb;
display:inline-block;
border-radius:5px;
}

#pages li a:hover
{
text-decoration:none;
color:#ff0080;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing information in your post about the html produced for the pagination.

I presume from your CSS that each page link is an anchor within a list item within an element with the id pages. I'm going to assume that the selected anchor has some sort of class on it, let's say "selected". Add something like this to your css:

```
#pages li a.selected
{
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```